# Can't recognize the global variable

Tags: java, variables, global

Why can't my compiler recognize the global value I made? Here is my code:

```
public class decoder_{
public static int c;//counter
public static double temp[];//for table upper
public static double temp1[];//for table lower
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
```

Then I use it inside `main`:

```
case 'a':
lower = lower + (current_range *la);
upper = lower+ (current_range *ha);
temp[c]= upper;
temp1[c]=lower;
c++;
break;
```

There is no compilation error, but the following message appears at runtime [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ZMS.png):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at decoder_.main(decoder_.java:95)
```

Comment: That exception is an error.

Comment: There wouldn't be much more to learn from that stack trace.  NPE in the main method is pretty much all there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not creating your arrays.   Try this:

```
public static double temp[] = new double[10];//for table upper
public static double temp1[] = new double[10];//for table lower
```

You might come up with better names for your arrays, too.

Comment: i don't know how i miss that , any ways  how could i make the length of the array  vary according to c increment ,for example if the c increment twice the array length is 2 , if it increment more then the array length become taller , not just const as 10 , many thanks

Comment: If you want to vary the length, don't use an array.  Perhaps ArrayList<Double> is what you want.  Or maybe a Deque of some sort.  Read up on [java collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).